# loop an ArrayList of Object into my JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I look for the way to make a loop to show a list of people's in my JSP, but nothing displays when I make the code below:

*My ArrayList "resultArray" consists of objects "Person":*

```
[Person{id=1, namePerson='Tom'}, 
 Person{id=2, namePerson='Paul'}, 
 Person{id=3, namePerson='Mary'}, 
 Person{id=4, namePerson='Luky'}]
```

*Here is my code into my JSP file:*

```
<%@ page import="mypath.Person" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<html>
<%
   ArrayList<Person> userList=(ArrayList<Person>) request.getAttribute("resultArray");
   if(userList != null) {
         for(Person u : userList) {
              u.getId();
              u.getNamePerson();
         }
    }
  %>
```

Comment: Why would anything display?

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling the method and you are not writing anything to outstream.

You should consider writing it to see in the page. For example

```
out.write(u.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="item">
    ${item.namePerson}<br>
</c:forEach>
```